# How can I select files which meet a condition in a directory structure

Tags: macos, unix, find

In have a big directory tree in OSX (Mountain Lion), and I need to delete all the files below a certain threshold filesize. I could create a duplicate of the directory excluding the small files, or simply delete them from the original directory.

I thought about using "find" but I can figure out how.

Thanks

Comment: Find has -size n[ckMGTP] Which is true if the file's size, **rounded up**, in 512-byte blocks is n. Is that precise enough or do you need to delete small files yet keep other than 512 bytes?  (Syntax for files up to 10kb would be `find . -size +10k -print`. Combined with -exec and rm, or -delete)

Comment: Needless to say, first **test** with echo rather than rm.  E.g. with `find . -size +100k -exec echo Would delete {} \;`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `find`.  To remove all files smaller than 12345 bytes:

```
find somedir -type f -size -12345c -delete
```

Please test this out before you use it!  You can see which files will be affected by running the find without the delete first:

```
find somedir -type f -size -12345c
```

The `c` modifier to the size tells it to count bytes.  Hennes above was on the right track, but both GNU find and the BSD find that comes with OSX support the `c` byte-count modifier.  See the man page for find; there are other options available if you only care about the size in kilobytes or megabytes.

Comment: Or simply `find … -delete` – no need for the pipe and and `xargs`.

Comment: Thanks.  I have some sort of mental block against `-delete`.  Been using it with xargs for like 20 years. :)